# Weird errors in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've recently changed a few lines of code in my app, and it screwed all of it.
There a few weird errors I would like to note here, hoping some of you will know a solution to it-

First- I'm implementing the delegate of UITextField in my app, put it in those , but still in my .m file when I try to implement this method-

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

It shows this error- Use of undeclared identifier 'textFieldDidBeginEditing'.
Second and third, there are two parse issues- Expected '}' and  Missing '@end'. When I add Missing @end from the red circle with a little white square in it button, it shows me the same error again- infinite loop.
How can I solve these?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the actual errors are not where you (and the compiler) think(s) it is. Deducing from the error message you got, you're missing a closing curly bracket (`}`) from the part of your code which falls *before* the line which errors out.

Comment: Whoa! That worked! Thank you so much! H2CO3 you're so ~Awesomeness~.